# Send on SSO custom informations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, wif

I'm reading up on SSO with WIF STS and so on. Im ended up in this tutorial http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx .

I wonder how I can recive some custom data which I would like to send from the custom STS?

The Relying Party in this tutorial has no code which is evalulating the response from the STS. If I'm correct this is done by the Idendity.Model.Service.

How can I send data from the IdP and recive them in the RP? Is it also possible to send some custom information on the SSO from RP to IdP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the article: "The second method, the GetOutputClaimsIdentity(), is just as simple. All that is need here, is to create a new ClaimsIdentity and add the required claims. In this case, I only set the Name and NameIdentifier claims."

So you can set any claims you want using this method - normally you would get the attributes from a repository like AD.

The RP is built using WIF so you have a bunch of built-in methods. Refer: [WIF Claims Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)